# @CreatedDate annotation does not work with spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring-boot-data-elasticsearch to persist the documents into elasticsearch.

Below is my Document Object for it.

```
@Builder
@Document(indexName = "testidx", createIndex = false)
public class Book {
    @Id
    private final String _id;

    @NotNull
    @CreatedDate
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.basic_date_time)
    private final Instant regTime;

    @NotNull
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private final String bookName;
}
```

However, when I saved the object into the ElasticSearchRepository, the regTime(which has to be created and saved automatically by @CreatedDate), has not been saved.

```
elasticRepository.save(
            Book.builder()
                .bookName("test")
                .build()
        );
```

```
GET /testidx/_search

{
        "_index" : "testidx",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "M3IS_XgBGpcXDVxetXXn",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "_class" : "{test class Name}",
          "bookName" : "test",
        }
      }
```

Could you please let me know what I have been missed?

I'm working on the spring-boot 2.4.5 (and spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch 2.4.5 also) and ElasticSearch 7.12.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the documentation about auditing (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.0/reference/html/#elasticsearch.auditing).

Your entity needs to implement the `Persistable` interface and needs to reimplement the `isNew()` method (see section 9.2.1).
Note: I just saw that in the documented entity sample the `@CreatedDate` and `@CreatedBy` annotations are missing. I will fix the docs, the annotation is needed of course.

Then do you have `@EnableElasticsearchAuditing` on your Spring Boot application or any other configuration class? This is needed as well.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I should implement the Persistable interface. Now it works! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Sorry, but just one more thing; could I add `@EnableElasticsearchAuditing` on any config class? (e.g - RestClientConfig)

Comment: any class that is also annotated with `@Configuration` - or one of the composed annotations like `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I have done this, but I'm getting a weird error: "Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchAuditingHandler': Cannot create inner bean ...PersistentEntitiesFactoryBean" and "No qualifying bean of type ...MappingElasticsearchConverter". Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately *spring-data-elasticsearch* does not support all persistence related annotations, neither all of the [mapping-annotations of JPA](https://dzone.com/articles/all-jpa-annotations-mapping-annotations), nor the [auditing-annotations of *Spring-Data*](https://springbootdev.com/2018/03/13/spring-data-jpa-auditing-with-createdby-createddate-lastmodifiedby-and-lastmodifieddate/), where `@CreatedDate` belongs to.

#### Solution

So I would drop it and just use the basic `@Field` annotation.
Then your property `regTime` should show up in JSON request as sibling above `bookName` and be persisted as expected.

However, without the special feature of *Spring-Data*'s `@CreatedDate` annotation (convenience for auditing), **you have to care for initialization yourself**, set the value before persisting, e.g. using `regTime = Instant.now()` (either in field definition, in constructor, or else).

#### Background

See the docs for *Meta Model Object Mapping*, [6.1.1. Mapping Annotation Overview](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.0/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.annotations) which currently (version 4.2) only includes these **field annotations**:

- `@Id`
- `@Field`
- `@GeoPoint`

See also the official guide [8. Elasticsearch Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.0/reference/html/#elasticsearch.repositories).

Formerly there was an enum [SUPPORTED_ID_PROPERTY_NAMES](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/mapping/SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.java#L66) in [SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.0/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/mapping/SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.html) which listed these field-annotations.

See similar question: [Does Spring Data Elasticsearch supports @Id annotation from JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894389/does-spring-data-elasticsearch-supports-id-annotation-from-jpa)

This tutorial helped me as introduction to elasticsearch-data:
[Spring Boot Elastic Search Example - Java Developer Zone](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-elastic-search-example/#25_Creating_a_Document)

Comment: This has nothing to do with JPA. `@CreatedBy` is a Spring Data annotation used by the different Spring Data modules.  And it's just the purpose of these annotations and the auditing that the user does not have to initialize these fields by herself.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Thank you for the review and hinting this difference. Didn't know the purpose: auditing (although pretty obvious and a convenient feature). Hope my update fixed the misconception.