# How can your createdDate and modifedDate fields be automatically initialized with client-side timestamps in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch. In traditional JPA, I would generate timestamps like this

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class) // ←
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @CreatedDate // ←
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    // the rest is omitted for brevity
```

However, the same combination of the same `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)` + `@CreatedDate`/`@ModifiedDate` wouldn't work with Elastic since `@EntityListeners` is from `javax.persistence` which has nothing to do with Elastic and other noSQL systems. I came across this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67225213/21530803). So, if I understand correctly, I should do these things

1. Have my `@Document` implement `Persistable`
2. Still have `@CreatedDate` and `@ModifiedDate` (even though they are *still*, as of this writing, [not in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.0/reference/html/#elasticsearch.auditing))
3. Include `@EnableElasticsearchAuditing` in your `@Configuration` class

Is that enough? Some questions I have in mind

1. Do your `createdDate`/`modifiedDate` have to be of certain type? Would `LocalDateTime` be fine?
2. Will the timestamps truly reflect the client-side timezone?
3. Is `@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.basic_date_time)` required? Or would some nice default conversions happen without extra involvement on my side? The Spring documentation referenced above does include them for date fields *but not other fields* which starts to look purposeful to me (but since the docs are apparently not perfectly maintained, it just as well may mean nothing at all)

In summary, **how can your createdDate and modifedDate fields be automatically initialized with client-side timestamps in Elasticsearch?**